# Delayed job argument error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, delayed-job

I'm having bother with delayed_job using the active_record fork ([link](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job_active_record)).

In the controller:

```
guide = Rightsguide.new
guide.run(@works, current_user)
```

in the Rightsguide ruby class:

```
require 'delayed_job'
require 'delayed/tasks'
require 'prawn'
require 'open-uri'

class Runrightsguide

  def run(works, current_user)
    pdf = Rightsguidereport.new(works, current_user)
    filename     = "#{Rails.root}/public/#{Date.today}_rightsguide.pdf"
    pdf.render_file(filename)
    pdf_file = File.open(filename)
    archive = RightsguideArchive.new(:user_id => current_user)
    archive.pdf = pdf_file
    archive.save!

    User.find(current_user).notice "<a href='/rightsguide_archives' target='_blank'>View Rights Guide</a>", :level => :notice, :sticky => true, :title => "AIs generated." 
  end

end
```

The above works fine, but when I use one of the delayed_job calls such as `handle_asynchronously :run` after the `run` method I get `wrong number of arguments (2 for 1)`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hmm. Turns out the `@works` argument was the problem. It's an ActiveRecord relation. Delayed_job didn't like it. Turning the relation into an array of IDs did the job.